# is there a way for get subsystem info of wildfly config with java?

Tags: java, wildfly

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">  
   <!-- ... -->  
    <servlet-container name="default" default-session-timeout="30">  
        <!-- ... -->  
    </servlet-container>  
    <!-- ... -->  
</subsystem>
```

I want to get value of **default-session-timeout** of above subsystem in java program. How to achieve that? I have searched around on internet but have not found any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to have a look at the [`ModelControllerClient`](http://docs.wildfly.org/15/Admin_Guide.html#working-with-a-modelcontrollerclient) API.

Something like this would do the trick:

```java
final ModelNode address = Operations.createAddress("subsystem", "undertow", "servlet-container", "default");
final ModelNode op = Operations.createReadAttributeOperation(address, "default-session-timeout");
try (ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create("localhost", 9990)) {
    final ModelNode result = client.execute(op);
    if (!Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(result)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(Operations.getFailureDescription(result).asString());
    }
    System.out.println(Operations.readResult(result).asInt());
}
```

If you're using Maven the dependency would be something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-controller-client</artifactId>
    <version>${version.org.wildfly.core}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: above code, default-session-timeout can be got in jboss eap

Comment: Yes. Which version of EAP are you using? The community artifacts can be used, but you can also use the product artifacts if you'd like.

Comment: It has not been decided yet but the high probability is 7.1